# obtener meses del año en android

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas, quiero tener un spinner lleno de todos los meses del año, pero sin usar una lista. obtener los meses y que en el spinner salga el mes actual del dispositivo.

alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esto debes primeramente debes realizar

#### Como obtener los meses del año en Java:

```
List<String> mesesList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    String month = months[i];
    System.out.println("Mes " + month);
    mesesList .add(months[i]);
}
```

#### Como llenar un Spinner:

Teniendo un `ArrayList` con datos, podemos llenar fácilmente nuestro `Spinner`.

```
   // Creación de adapter para spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mesesList);

    // Define estilo.
myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Adjunta datos del adapter al spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**Para que en el Spinner se muestre el mes correspondiente en el dispositivo.**

Primeramente debes obtener el mes actual mediante:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String mesActual = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

este texto compararlo con los elementos dentro del `Adapter` del `Spinner`:

```
    int indexmonth = 0;
    //mesesList es una lista que contiene los nombres de los meses.
    for (int i =0; i< mesesList.size();i++) {
        //Compara el mes actual con los textos desplegados en el spinner.
        if(mesActual.equals(String.valueOf(myAdapter.getItem(i)))){
            //Obtiene el indice de la coincidencia.
            indexmonth = i;
        }
    }
```

Posteriormente posicionamos el Spinner en la posición que corresponde al mes actual:

```
//Mueve spinner a la posición
spinner.setSelection(indexmonth);
```

Comment: puedes decirme en el caso de los dias, pero en texto?